# Running a backround service by applying server Timezone in javascript using node-schedule (Node.js.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, timezone, node-schedule

Hello stack overflow community,

I am an absolute beginner with regard to how servers configuration works.
Currently, I have an app to be scheduled at a **specific time, for every 5 minutes. (8:00 am - 10:00PM Malaysia Time, (GMT+8)).** But my server is using **Eastern Daylight Time, (EDT).**

So how do I write it in my program so it will run on the 8-9 PM Malaysia time.

Below is my current code.

```
var schedule = require("node-schedule");

schedule.scheduleJob("*/5 8-22 * * *", function () {
//Some code to get data
  });
```

Thanks for any helps in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is *Eastern Daylight Time, (EDT)* equal to **GMT-4** and you want to run your code at **8:00 GMT+8**

Then it would be from **8 P.M (20:00) the day BEFORE to 10 A.M CURRENT DAY** in EDT time.

For this case, maybe you would like to see this [cronjob over midnight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67158/crontab-entry-with-hour-range-going-over-midnight?noredirect=1&lq=1). Good luck.